# How do I convert a column from "unknown" to date in R to use ggplot scale_x_date?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a column in my dataframe which shows as "unknown" when I hover the cursor over the column title. It shows as a date as printed below with `head(dataframe)`

Example data:

```
date<date>  courses<int>  tasks<int>
1   2020-01-02  14      199
2   2020-01-03  14      246
3   2020-01-06  14      227
4   2020-01-07  14      83
5   2020-01-08  14      116
6   2020-01-09  14      178
```

I have tried:

1. Formatting the column as "date" in excel before importing
2. Changing the import settings to "date" when loading both CSV and XLS files
3. Importing the data as "character" and them changing to numeric and then date. This does provide the correct format but the same "unknown" heading.

I was able to add a week column, so it seems like the data is behaving as a date in some instances but not others.

```
DFweek <- dataframe %>% mutate(Week = week(date))
head(DFweek)

date<date>  courses<int>  tasks<int>  <week><dbl>
1   2020-01-02  14      199 1
2   2020-01-03  14      246 1
3   2020-01-06  14      227 1
4   2020-01-07  14      83  1
5   2020-01-08  14      116 2
6   2020-01-09  14      178 2
```

The column always shows as a date type

```
> class(dataframe$date)
[1] "Date"

> str(dataframe$date)
 Date[1:290], format: "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-09" "2020-01-10" "2020-01-13" "2020-01-14"
```

This code successfully makes a plot

```
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1]

dataframeplot <- ggplot(dataframe, aes(date, courses)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_bar(aes(y = a + tasks*b), color = "red", stat='identity') +
  scale_y_continuous("Open Courses", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Tasks Completed")) +
  scale_x_continuous("Month", breaks = 1:12) +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red")
        
        ) 
dataframeplot
```

I would like to use scale_x_date, but the below code gives me an error

```
> dataframeplot2<- ggplot(dataframe, aes(date, courses)) +
+   geom_line() +
+   geom_bar(aes(y = a + tasks*b), color = "red", stat='identity') +
+   scale_y_continuous("Open Courses", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Tasks Completed")) +
+   scale_x_date("Month", breaks = 1:12) +
+   ggtitle("Title") +
+   theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
+         axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
+         axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"), 
+         axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red")
+         
+         ) 
> dataframeplot2
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Does this mean that my date column isn't actually in date format?

Comment: I don't think the issue is your data. The issue is that you don't pass a `Date` variable to `breaks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `scale_x_date("Month", breaks = 1:12)` to `scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month")`. See documentation for `scale_x_date()`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/scale_x_date